# OpenBSD Unix Wifi Wireless Networking IDIMAX N150 USB Wifi dongle issue

Tags: wifi, openbsd

I was able to successfully install OpenBSD 6.6 on a Dell Latitude e6400 laptop I have, that I installed an SSD drive on. It works great with Ethernet LAN with cat6 cable to my internet router, no issues there, but I was trying to also enable it to work with Wifi.

I purchased an IDIMAX N150 usb wifi dongle, and plugged it in to my laptop.

First, I updated the firmware with `fw_update -a`, no problems there.

Then I created this hostname file

`/etc/hostname.urtwn0`

and added this line to the file:

```
dhcp nwid ATTklaaxYs wpakey password-here
```

Then I ran netstart script manually with the following command:

```
sh /etc/netstart urtwn0
```

this is the output I get after running netstart:

```
urtwn0: link...........sleeping
```

and also, here is what the ifconfig command shows after running the netstart command:

```
$ ifconfig urtwn0

urtwn0: flags=808843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST,AUTOCONF4> mtu 1500
lladdr 08:be:ac:03:59:46
index 6 priority 4 llprio 3
groups: wlan
media: IEEE802.11 autoselect (DS1)
status: no network
ieee80211: nwid ATTklaaxYs wpakey wpaprotos wpa2 wpaakms psk wpaciphers ccmp wpagroupcipher ccmp
inet 23.202.231.169 netmask 0xff000000 broadcast 23.255.255.255
```

Now the error appears to be the STATUS with NO NETWORK, which instead should be ACTIVE. Has anyone encountered the same issue before? and if so, what was your fix?

Answer (score 0):

Does the `nwid` show up with `ifconfig urtwn0 scan`?  If so, note what protocols are listed at the end of each line, some APs only support `wpa1` and you must add `wpaprotos wpa1` to the appropriate line on `hostname.urtwn0` (or to `ifconfig`), otherwise it might not connect.

Where did the `23.202.231.169` come from?  Did you set it manually before `netstart`ing the device, or did it connect, get the IP via DHCP and then disconnect?

Not likely the root of your problem, but the lines on `/etc/hostname.*` files are executed sequentially, one at a time so you might want to change it to

```
nwid ATTklaaxYs wpa wpakey <password>
dhcp
```

That way the radio part will be dealt with first and only then `dhclient` will ask for an IP address.

Comment: OK thanks for your input, I am not sure where the 23.202.x.x IP came from, I did not set it manually, I will try your suggestions later today and see if they work. Will post on here the results. Once again, Thanks :-)